Fisher's Linear Discriminant analysis scatter matrix
I am reading about Linear Discriminant Analysis, especially Fisher's discriminat function which solves and optimization problem $Max\dfrac{w^TS_Bw}{w^TS_Ww}$. Lets say i have a two class problem. The maximizer exists at $S_Bw= \lambda S_W w$. Making this into a generalized eigenvalue problem. Now i havesome doubts. The matrix used here is $S_W$ which is the sum of two covariance matrix for class1 and class2. Why do people say it as a scatter matrix. The empirical covariance for class1  should be $S_1=  \dfrac{1}{n_1-1}(X_1X_1^T-\mu_1\mu_1^T)$
The empirical covariance for class2  should be $S_2=  \dfrac{1}{n_2-1}(X_2X_2^T-\mu_2\mu_2^T)$
where $S_W= S_1+S_2$. Do we just sum these two matrices or take their average.
Next my question is the objective value of the function becomes $\lambda$ which is the largest eigenvalue.  Third doubt is why does LDA gives at most 1 discriminat direction. See even if the matrix $S_W^{-1}S_B$ is rank $1$ it will have 2 distinct eigenvalues so we will have 2 linearly indepensent eigenvectors. So there should be atmost 2 discriminating direction, leave alone the fact the eigenvector corresponding to the $0$ eigenvalue will not be useful. Can somebody help?

Let $X_{ik} := (X_{ik}^1, X_{ik}^2, \dots, X_{ik}^p)$ denote the observation $k$ in group $i$. We assume that the true mean and variance-covariance matrix in group $i$ are given by $\mu_i$ and $\Sigma_i$, respectively. Let $N := n_1 + n_2$ denote the total sample size. If $\Sigma_1 = \Sigma_2$ and $n_1 = n_2$, we could pool all observations to estimate the variance-covariance matrix, i.e., $$\hat S :=\frac{1}{N -1}\sum_{i=1}^2\sum_{k=1}^{n_i}(X_{ik} - \overline X_{\cdot\cdot})(X_{ik} - \overline X_{\cdot\cdot})^\top$$ with $$\overline X_{\cdot\cdot} := \frac 1N\sum_{i=1}^2\sum_{k=1}^{n_i}X_{ik}.$$ If $\Sigma_1 = \Sigma_2$ and $n_1\neq n_2$ or $\mu_1 \neq \mu_2$, we should not pool the observations but pool the estimators to acknowledge this heterogeneity, i.e., $$\hat S := \frac{1}{N-2}\sum_{i=1}^2\sum_{k=1}^{n_i}(X_{ik} - \overline X_{i\cdot})(X_{ik} - \overline X_{i\cdot})^\top$$ with $$\overline X_{i\cdot} := \frac{1}{n_i}\sum_{k=1}^{n_i}X_{ik}.$$
If $\Sigma_1\neq\Sigma_2$, we can use the sum of estimators as an estimator for the variance-covariance matrix of the group differences, i.e., $$\hat S := \sum_{i=1}^2\left(\frac{1}{n_i - 1}\sum_{k=1}^{n_i}(X_{ik} - \overline X_{i\cdot})(X_{ik} - \overline X_{i\cdot})^\top\right).$$
So depending on your believes about the underlying data generating process, you may chose one estimator or another. Scatter matrix is a common term used for objects used to make estimates about the variance-covariance matrix.
Can you expand your last question. It is difficult for me to understand what you mean.

Lets say we have $n_1\neq n_2$ and $S_1\neq S_2$, then should I use the pooled sample estimator that diviides by $(n_1+n_2-2)$, or should I just sum $S_1 +S_2$

Be careful: $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ are the true variance-covariance matrices. If you believe that your data is heteroscedastic (i.e., variance-covariance matrices differ across groups), then you should use the last estimator. However, $\Sigma_1 = \Sigma_2$ is often a standard assumption in LDA. On the other hand, QDA deals with situations in which $\Sigma_1\neq\Sigma_2$ (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_classifier)
